# Adobe Acrobate Reade 2017 Javascript Textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I'm currently working on a pdf form that should send an email via click on a button with the given informations.

Everything is working so far expect if I fill up the last textbox (doesn't matter which one) and click directly on sendmail.

I get the value from the textboxes like this:

`var c_annotation = this.getField('Text29').value;`

At the end of the script it will just send a mail with `this.Maildoc()`.
If I close the mail and click the button again, the value of the textbox is in the var `c_annotation`.

It seems like the value isn't properly set, but I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: Can you please more of your code, it is pretty hard to say what's wrong with just those few lines

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry but there is really nothing more than this.
Just a few textboxes and the Maildoc()

Comment: The placement of the code could be important, maybe you've put something inside/outside of the scope, or something like that. It does not seem realistic to me that someone can help you with currently provided samples